# How to get TicketMaster event id from event URL?

Tags: php, api, ticketmaster

I currently have access to Ticketmaster's Discovery API. I want to take a link like this

```
https://www1.ticketmaster.com/zpl-jingle-jam-featuring-lizzo-why-dont-we/event/05005726960D2E82
```

and use the ID to get event data from Discovery API. When I tried in API explorer it said ID was wrong. I found out the ID is actually `vv16AZAjJPOZACd2ad`.

Is there any way to use ID from the URL to reference the given event? I see you can in partner API, but that's not easy to join from what I see.

If that's not at all possible, how are people able to create stock checkers in discord? For example: `!stock 05005726960D2E82` would return stock remaining for the given event broken down by sections.

Comment: If worse comes to worse, you can always scrape the page of the said link and grab the DiscoveryId from there. If you look at the source code of the link and perform a search you can it is in there... vv16AZAjJPOZACd2ad

Comment: @norcaljohnny I spoke with their support and I guess discovery API doesn't offer what I was looking for.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I just want to see if the tickets for a particular event are available or not. Is there any way, with/out the API? Scrapping isn't an option since the information is loaded after the page load. So, while using fetch(), we do not get the dynamic information about the availability of tickets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with discovery API since that wasn't it's intended purpose.

Comment: I do not think this actually gives an answer since the question is "How to get TicketMaster event id from event URL?" and you actually can. with PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not from the URL, you have to get it from the source code, the event id for the API is under disco_event_id in the html code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34323094)